# Limitation of storing Documents inside SharePoint online compared to SharePoint on-premises and file shares

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2010, document-library, migration, content-migration

We want to move all the documents we have from SharePoint 2010 & Windows server 2012 to SharePoint Online sites. On some cases we will use Power Shell to do the move Or for small folders we will drag-drop those files.

But what i am not sure about is what are the limitations of storing documents inside SharePoint online compared to SharePoint 2010 and File shares, regarding those main areas:-

1. Single File size
2. File Path Length
3. Allowed charterers inside the File name

I think with SharePoint 2010 and File shares we do not have any limitations (or the limitations are less), compared to SharePoint online.. but i am unable to find any documentation which list those limitations so i can know them in advance?

Thanks

Comment: While this doesn't directly answer your question, my recommendation would be to have a look at the migration tools within the SharePoint admin center to scan your existing file shares and SharePoint 2010 environment to identify any potential issues. https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/AdminHome.aspx#/migration

Comment: @user79408 the link you provided does not work

Comment: you will need to replace "contoso" with your sharepoint online domain. eg if your sharepoint address is https://johnGu.sharepoint.com, the address you would need is https://johnGu-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/AdminHome.aspx#/migration

Answer (score 2):

This [Microsoft Support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/restrictions-and-limitations-in-onedrive-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa#:%7E:text=SharePoint%20Server%20versions%20only%20support,ll%20receive%20an%20error%20message.) lays out the limits. Check back often, because they may change at any time. As of writing they are

1. Maximum file upload size updated to 250 GB.
2. The answer is complex, but short: not more than 400 characters
3. not allowed are " * : < > ? / \ | and leading/trailing spaces

Windows Server (file shares) doesn't have a file size limit. Path length is application dependent (Office apps don't like paths > 256 characters), and special character rules are similar.

You want to do an inventory of your file shares to get a picture of YOUR environment, though, so you can identify problems before migration.

Comment: thanks a lot .. but my question is; are those limitations applied to SharePoint 2010 and File Shares? if those limitations do apply then i do not have to worry about migrating the documents to SP online.. but if those limitations do not apply then i need to solve those issues.. did you get my main question/concern?

Comment: I am finding articles with the specifics quite easily with a google search, so why can't you find them? File path: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd.  -- Invalid characters:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file -- Windows Server doesn't have a file size limit.

Comment: NTFS has varying file size limits; practically they are meaningless today (16 EiB, though limited to 8 PiB in current implementations of Windows Server with 2048 KiB cluster format; ReFS is 35 PiB). The file size limit entirely depends on what file system the volume is formatted in (i.e., a non-Windows file server using ext4 or ZFS may have different limits) and potentially cluster size used in the format.

Comment: @TrevorSeward  ok thanks for the info,,, but if we compare SharePoint 2010 with SharePoint online.. could we have files that can exists inside SharePoint 2010 but can not exists inside SharePoint online due to their size, characters used in the name or their path length? Thanks

Comment: SharePoint Online exceeds all limitations of SharePoint 2010 in terms of file paths length, character limitations, and size.

Comment: @TrevorSeward so you mean the limitations are less on SharePoint online compared to SharePoint 2010? i thought the opposite is true..

Comment: SharePoint Online is more advanced, mature, etc., so I'm not sure what lead you to that thought process. 2010 has far more limitations for all of the categories you've asked about.